# How to make brush size lock in texture paint

Tags: texturing

I need to lock brush size in texture paint mode (not relative to zoom), but it's aviavle only in scupt mode
[image: Screenshot of lock posibility in sculpt mode]

How to make it happen in texture paint mode?

Answer (score 1):

With Blender 2.79.

By default, with a 'tiled' brush mapping, not only the brush texture size is changed with zooming, but the brush texture is also offset when changing the angle of view.

[image]

However, the brush mapping can be changed to '3D' to prevent resulting in texture painting interference by view resize/change.

[image]

From Blender 2.79 [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/texture_tex_mask.html):

> The 3D option allows the brush to take full advantage of procedural
>   textures. This mode uses vertex coordinates rather than the brush
>   location to determine what area of the texture to use.

Note that it works perfectly with image texture as well.

Comment: Very nice explaination but could you please update it for 2.80.