# Lock radius of brush in texture paint mode

Tags: texture-painting, sculpting

This question has also been asked before but since it did not get any answer im asking again with the hope of getting any kind of feedback or possibly an answer since the original post had none .In sculpting mode the paint brush radius/size can be locked so the brush size doesn't change when zooming. This feature seems to be absent in texture painting, is there any work around in achieving that in texture paint mode ? Guidelines for a making a Python script would be useful.

[image]

Comment: Here is the original post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74165/how-to-make-brush-size-lock-in-texture-paint

Comment: Is this the same exact question as the other? Usually is good practice to not duplicate a question. To increase the chance of getting an answer you can 1) edit the question adding more detais/showing your progress to make it clear the goal 2) put a bounty on it.

Comment: Thank you from answering, sorry I'm relatively new to stack exchange so I might not know some things. You can mark this post as duplicate.

Comment: An answer has been posted on the [original question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74165/how-to-make-brush-size-lock-in-texture-paint). I guess this one should be closed as 'duplicate'.